# Meteor Iron.Router dynamic template

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a HomeLayout.html like this:

```
<template name="HomeLayout">
  <main>
     {{>Template.dynamic template=main}}
  </main>
</template>
```

And a LoginLayout.html like this:

```
<template name="LoginLayout">
  <main>
     <p> Login Layout Test </p>
  </main>
</template>
```

I'm trying to input this LoginLayout inside HomeLayout.
To start the HomeLayout I use this code:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('HomeLayout');
});
```

But i dont know how i can load this LoginLayout inside HomeLayout...

Answer (score 1):

Just define a helper that returns the template you want to dynamically insert:

```
Template.HomeLayout.helpers({
  main: function(){
    return "LoginLayout";
  }
});
```

Where you have `{{>Template.dynamic template=main}}` the above helper will evaluate `main` as a helper and that will return the layout you're looking for.

I don't know what your `<main></main>` tags are doing however.

Comment: Doesn't Iron router work with {{> yield}} and use the current route name to find a matching template?

Comment: @JanJoukeTjalsma yes but dynamic templates are not normally controlled by i-r, they are controlled by whatever provides the variable passed to the dynamic template. Dynamic templates provide an extra level of control over `{{> yields}}` and are useful when, for example, you want to share event maps across templates.